# Rails4 Form with remote - handling error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, error-handling

I have a simple remote form like this:

`= form_for :question, :url => question_path, :remote => true, :html =>{:class => 'question-form'} do |form|`

and in my controller I check if in the form the EULA is accepted:

```
  def create
    if (params[:question][:eula] != 1)
      puts "ERROR!"
      respond_to do |format|
          return format.json {render :json => {:error_message => "FOOOO", :success => false } }
      end
    end
    @question = Question.new(question_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @question.save
        format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'question was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @question }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**How can I access `:error_message` or `:success` in my create.js.erb file?**

Comment: you have to respond `format.js`, also you have to have create.js.erb file if calling it as `remote: true`

Comment: yes but how I can access `:json => {:error_message => "FOOOO", :success => false }` in my `create.js.erb file?

Answer (score 0):

You can do Ajax request

add id to form `:id => "question-form"`

```
= form_for :question, :url => question_path, :remote => true, 
                  :html =>{:class => 'question-form', :id => "question-form"} do |form|
```

and anywhere in javascript file

```
$("#question-form").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var request = $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
        url: "/questions",
        dataType: "json",
        data: form.serialize()
    })

    request.done(function(res){
        console.log(res.success);
    })

    request.catch(function(jqXHR){
        console.log(jqXHR.responseJSON)
    })

})
```

Comment: Wouldn't you end up with two async requests to the same endpoint this way?

Answer (score 0):

> **How can I access `:error_message` or `:success` in my create.js.erb file?**

The Rails way (though it has certain downsides) would be to continue using `remote: true` in your form and then consume instance variables in your create.js.erb template rather than to render JSON.

```rb
def create
  @error_message = "FOOOO"
  @success = false

  render "create", handlers: ["js.erb"]
end
```

(I've simplified the controller a bit – you can still respond to specific formats and so on.)

Those instance variables will then be available in create.js.erb:

```js
<% if @success %>
  console.log('success');
<% end %>
```